# Selenium cannot handle large table row count

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on this project that requires returning the number of tr's in the table. I saved the tr webElement in a list and its crashing due to the number of rows in the table. The table sometimes can have about 100,000 rows. After about 4 mins of not responding, it throws this error msg "Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000". Here is what i have so far.

WebElement getTable = driver.findElement(tableElement);

WebElement getTbody = getTable.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));

List valueList = getTbody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

System.out.println( valueList.size() )

Basically, it stops or tries to get the tr into a list (valueList) but eventually crashes. 
Anyone every experienced this before?

Comment: Does adding an implicit wait help you ? driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Comment: Yes, i added 240 sec. I increased the wait time but the application would time out after 20 mins of wait.

Answer (score 2):

It's crashing because you have low memory to handle those large objects..

You can use JavaScript executor to get your row length..

((JavaScript Executor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length");

Comment: Thanks. It worked with the above. It returned a value but have to test if the count is all the rows on the web page or my result table. However the difficult part is over. Thanks again.